# How to extract repeated pattterns from a string

Tags: r, gsub, regex-lookarounds

I need to extract certain patterns from the text below.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Budget 2016-2017 
Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Budget 2015-2016 mauris ut leo. Cras 
viverra metus rhoncus sem
```

I need to get the 'Budget \d{4}-\d{4}' part of the text so it looks like:

```
 [1] "Budget 2016-2017" "Budget 2015-2016"
```

Comment: Usually there are easier ways. How do you get that string? In the package `rvest` there's a function that allows you to do `rvest::html_text()` on an object that is the result of e.g. `rvest::read_html(your_url)`

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: `stringr::str_extract_all(x, 'Budget [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get what you want with the following:

```
library(stringr)
string <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Budget 2016-2017 Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Budget 2015-2016 mauris ut leo. Cras  viverra metus rhoncus sem"

unlist(str_extract_all(string, 'Budget [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}'))
```

Result:

```
> unlist(str_extract_all(string, 'Budget [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}'))
[1] "Budget 2016-2017" "Budget 2015-2016"
```

Answer (score 0):

something close

```
s <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Budget 2016-2017 Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Budget 2015-2016 mauris ut leo. Cras  viverra metus rhoncus sem"

gsub(".*(Budget [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}).*", "\\1", s)
[1] "Budget 2015-2016"
```